# get the latest dated dictionary from list of dictionaries

Tags: json, python-3.x, django

I have list of dictionary objects with date and name and status.

```
elements = [
    {
        "PersonId": 301178,
        "Wwid": "10692133",
        "FullNm": "abc",
        "CompletionDt": "2015-04-29",
        "status": "Complete",
    },
    {
        "PersonId": 301178,
        "Wwid": "10692133",
        "FullNm": "abc",
        "CompletionDt": "2019-07-30",
        "status": "complete",
    },
    {
        "PersonId": 301178,
        "Wwid": "10692133",
        "FullNm": "abc",
        "CompletionDt": "2016-08-01",
        "status": "Inclomplete",
    },
    {
        "PersonId": 301178,
        "Wwid": "10692133",
        "FullNm": "abc",
        "CompletionDt": "2017-04-10",
        "status": "Completed",
    },
]
```

In this dictionary how to pick the latest dated object using python?

In the above example

```
result= {
"PersonId": 301178,
"Wwid": "10692133",
"FullNm": "abc",
"CompletionDt": "2019-07-30",
"status" : "complete"
}
```

Comment: can you please check  input data "elements", it is throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

result = sorted(
    elements, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["CompletionDt"], "%Y-%m-%d")
)[-1]
```

or you can try python built-in `max`.

```
result = max(elements, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["CompletionDt"], "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**Output:**

```
{'PersonId': 301178, 'Wwid': '10692133', 'FullNm': 'abc', 'CompletionDt': '2019-07-30', 'status': 'complete'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am going to assume that your objects' ID is getting larger as time goes on (the later an object is created, the larger the ID) as comparing `DateTime` objects will be a pain - or unnecessary.

```py
qs = Person.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
```

Basically you sort it by *reversing* ID order (largest --> smallest) and then retrieve the first item, which will be the latest created object in the queryset
if my assumption above stands.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = max(x['CompletionDt'] for x in myList)
```

Comment: are you sure this will give the intended results?

Comment: I tested it locally and it works on the dataset provided. I believe python can interpret that date format as a string without having to convert it manually